# Let $\{ x_{n}\}$ be a sequence such that there exists $0 < C < 1$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}| \leq C|x_{n} - x_{n-1}|$. Show $\{x_{n}\}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm stuck, this is what I've tried so far:

$|x_{n} - x_{m}| = |x_{n} - x_{n-1} + x_{n-1} -x_{n-2} + x_{n-2} + ... + x_{m}| \leq$ 
$|x_{n} - x_{n-1}| + |x_{n-1} -x_{n-2}| +  ... +|x_{m+1} - x_{m}| \leq (1 + C + ... + C^{n})\cdot |x_{m+1} - x_{m}| = \frac{1-C^{n+1}}{ 1 - C} |x_{m+1} - x_{m}| $

And now I'm stuck trying to show $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists M$ with $n\geq M$ that implies that it can be $< \varepsilon$.

Comment: You are pretty close. Can you check that $|x_{m+1} - x_m| \leq C^m |x_1 - x_0|$?

Comment: In the sum there are $m-n$ terms, so the factor should be $1 + C + \ldots + C^{m-n-1} = \frac{1-C^{m-n}}{1-C}$.

Comment: I'm going to assume $n > m$ wlog, so would it be $n-m+1$ terms?

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm pretty sure what you said is guaranteed by hypothesis.

Comment: Oh yeah, right, I haven't noticed that $n > m$. So just swap $n$ and $m$ in my comment above. There are $n-m$ terms, not $n-m+1$ - you might want to check it on some example.

Comment: @Adayah I think it should be $n-m+1$ terms.

Comment: Let's check for $n = m+3$: $|x_{m+3} - x_m| \leqslant |x_{m+3} - x_{m+2}| + |x_{m+2} - x_{m+1}| + |x_{m+1} - x_m|$. $3$ terms, which is $n-m$. **Edit**: I just thought maybe you meant terms of the sequence ($x_n$ down to $x_m$ which is $n-m+1$ terms indeed) while I meant the number of summands in the sum ($|x_n - x_{n-1}|$ down to $|x_{m+1} - x_m|$ which is $n-m$ summands).

Comment: @Adayah $|x_{m+3}−x_{m+2}|+|x_{m+2}−x_{m+1}|+|x_{m+1}−x_{m}| \leq (C^{2} + C + 1)|x_{m+1}−x_{m}|$. The degree of $C$ is $n -m +1$ not $n-m$.

Comment: The degree of $C$ is $n-m\color{red}{-}1=2$ and it is $1$ less than the number of terms: $1, C, C^2$ are $3 = n-m$ terms.

Comment: @Adayah ah there we go, so it should be C^(n-m-1)

Comment: I've solved it!